# why StackOverflowError at runtime...?

Tags: java

```
class Test
{
 Test t = new Test();   
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    Test t = new Test();
    System.out.println(t);
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about initializer blocks (yours contains `Test t = new Test();`) and when they are executed. That should make it clearer.

Answer (score 11):

Because the `Test` constructor allocates a new `Test` object which allocates a new `Test` object which allocates a new `Test` object...etc.

Comment: When would you say it gives up?

Comment: When the stack gets filled!

Comment: @PrashanthBC the answer I was going for was ["never"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

Comment: @AndyTurner When your VM is done with your saddening code that tortures it.

Comment: @AndyTurner right, it doesn't give up - it gets smashed when the JVM runs out of patience ... erm stack ;)

Comment: @Thomas it was a tongue-in-cheek comment based upon the answerer's user name.

Comment: @AndyTurner Best comment I've seen on SO. I mean it.

Answer (score 0):

When the main() method will execute, it will create a new `Test` object. Once the new `Test`object is created means, it will initialize all the instance variable. While initializing instance variable again it is trying to create a new `Test` object. In heap memory it will keep on creating new `Test` object. Because of this you will get `java.lang.StackOverflowError` exception. To solve this exception make the first `Test` object as `static`.